# How to pass date value from gridview to datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

Currently I am working with Data Gridview and Datetime picker in VB.Net
And dont know how to pass the value from gridview to date time picker. please help

Below is Date Colume of gridview

[image]

This error occured after debug

[image]

I tried some code...

```
    Student_Admission.DateTimePicker2.Value = CDate(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value)
```

Comment: You don't need to pass anything anywhere.  Populate a `DataTable` or some other list and bind it to a single `BindingSource`, then bind that to both the grid and the individual controls, including the `DateTimePicker`.  When the user selects a row in the grid, the field values will be automatically displayed in the other controls.  Any changes made in the other controls will be automatically reflected in the grid.

Answer (score -1):

in the first code you are converting to date then ToString. The value of DTP obviously cant hold that. To adjust the format you need to add a .Format property

The second code you supplied should work assuming there is a value that can be a date in cell(1) of the current row

Edit. ok, so you're not actually calling .ToString("mm/dd//yyyy") you are actually expecting the value to format as such? that's not going to work either.